# Unable to add footer to Collection View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

All I need is a footer of height 50 with background color black. Nothing more. Forget the implementation below for some time and let me know how you would implement the same.

I am using the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "FooterView", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
        // configure footer view
        return view
    }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: 375, height: 100)
    }
```

However, no footer is attached to the collection view. I am not able to understand why this doesn't work and how I should correct this. Please help me correct this.

Comment: can you attach screenshot of size inspector, with footerview and headerview heights?

Comment: Have you set the `delegate` of the `UICollectionView`?

Comment: @hardikparmar, please check for edit. @ dani, yes

Comment: Is that a custom footer? Meaning, do you use a custom class for that `UICollectionReusableView`?

Comment: @Dani, no. Please help me put an empty footer of height 50 and background color as black. That's it. Thank you.

Comment: @EnrikQaz, as faar as above attached screen shot is concerned you haven't added anything in the reusable view. Try adding some view or button inside it and then check if it is shown on UI.

Comment: Try Implementing delegate method for footer view size: `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize` and return the size that you want.

Comment: @nikBhosale, check edit. It still doesn't work. Just forget what I implemented for sometime. How would you implement the same. I don't want a very customized footer. Just a footer with height 50, that's it.

Comment: Check the height of footer by selecting  `collection view -> size inspector`

Comment: Put a breakpoint or a print statement inside `collectionView(_:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:at:)` function and check if that gets called or not.

Comment: None worked. Please don't make guesses. :(

Comment: Have you you given some constraint to views that you have added inside this reusable view? If not please try to give some definite constraint. Like add Label and give height as 50, and top, bottom, left, right constraint.

Comment: yes i did. there are constraints.

Comment: you have implemented `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How I do it:**

1) Create custom footer class:

```
import UIKit

class BlackFooterView: UICollectionReusableView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .black
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

2) Register Footer class in `UICollectionView` and setup reference size (Usually in the `viewDidLoad` method of needed `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /// Class registration
    self.collectionView!.register(BlackFooterView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: footerReuseIdentifier)
    /// Reference size
    (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).footerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 50)
}
```

3) Implement delegate methods:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: footerReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)
    }
    /// Normally should never get here
    return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

4) Voila:
[image]

---

### Sample provided in **Swift 4.2**

**NB:**

1. Cells generation code is not included.
2. I used `UICollectionViewController` class for the sample, that's why `delegate` methods started from `override`
3. You can also create footers from XIBs. In that case registration should be done using [registerNib:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618101-register) method.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my way. I tested this and it works.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

     @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         collectionView.dataSource = self
     }

     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

         let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "Footer", for: indexPath)
         view.backgroundColor = .red
         return view
     }
}
```

Comment: I get : Type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'elementKindSectionFooter'. I'm using Swift 4.1

Comment: I'm using Swift 4.2 and `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` has been renamed. But use `UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter` and see if that works

Answer (score -2):

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter) {
        let footerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CartFooterCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath)
        // Customize footerView here
        return footerView
    } else if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader) {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "CartHeaderCollectionReusableView", for: indexPath)
        // Customize headerView here
        return headerView
    }
    fatalError()
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more info and use the code bracket.